# how to accept or reject input image at method show in controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to accept or reject some file like (image) at method show in laravel

I try to use a helper function `request()`
but I can't do with that

if somebody has a better idea 
please tell me 
thanks

```
$photos = [
            'image_national_code',
            'identify_certificate',
            'image_bill',
            'image_selfie_national_code',
        ];
        foreach ($photos as $photo) {
            if (request($photo))
            {
                if ('accept_'. $photo == false) {
                    if ( file_exists( public_path($photo) ) )
                    unlink( public_path($photo) );
                }
            }else {
                $photo = $photo;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```php
request()->file($photo)
```

instead of

```php
request($photo)
```